# continous console log in express graphql app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, graphql

I have the following code which starts up a graphql server. I am new to this tech, and wondering why it is printing my console log forever repeatedly even if i am not running any requests against it:

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { typeDefs } from "./typeDefs";
import { resolvers } from "./resolvers";
import { tradeTokenForUser } from './auth-helpers';

const HEADER_NAME = 'authorization';

const startServer = async () => {
    const app = express();
    const path = '/api';
    const port = 3000;
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
        context: async ({ req }) => {
            let authToken = null;
            let currentUser = null;

            try {
                authToken = req.headers[HEADER_NAME];
                console.log('print ---->', authToken);
                if (authToken) {
                    currentUser = await tradeTokenForUser(authToken);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn(`Unable to authenticate using auth token: ${authToken}`);
            }

            return {
                authToken,
                currentUser,
            };
        },
    });

    server.applyMiddleware({ app, path });
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://test:test@test.mlab.com:123/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});

    app.listen({ port }, () =>
        console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${port}${server.graphqlPath}`)
    );
};

startServer();
```

this log `console.log('print ---->', authToken);` is continuously printing in my console. 
Is this normal?

Comment: Having a `catch` with a simple warn message to the console is a definite code smell. How can you be sure your code is still in a valid state when a (random) exception occurs? Also why tags for [tag:npm]?

Comment: @Icepickle the only console log i am seeing is the `print ---->` one inside the try block. and it is continuously printing without me even hitting the code.

Comment: But isn't it being called upon every request to validate tokens?

Comment: Is your `GraphQL` playground open?

Comment: yeah my graphql playgroudn is open in another tab @goto1

Comment: If you close it, does the message disappear? There's a setting in the `GraphQL` playground that pings the server every few seconds

Comment: yeah it disapears now... but is this normal? how about in production? how is this supposed to work? @goto1

Comment: There's a setting in the `GraphQL` playground that allows you to turn that off. The setting is called `schema.polling.enable` and can be set to `false` - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnetzero/documents/master/docs/en/images/graphql_playground_settings.jpg. It has nothing to do with `GraphQL Apollo`, so it doesn't matter whether you're running things in production or not

Comment: @goto1 what is polling used for mainly? should it be disabled on prod?

Comment: Here's an article about it - https://medium.com/novvum/graphql-playground-v1-8-8-introducing-automatic-schema-reload-6c9da4bbd552. The `GraphQL` playground should only be enabled in development mode. If `NODE_ENV` is set to `production` then `Apollo` will automatically disable the playground. It should be only used in development, by you, for testing purposes